# QField large datasets from PostgreSQL as a viewer

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I currently use Esri ArcGIS Field Maps to display large datasets for our field guys to use while they are driving around such as parcels with information, contours etc. All are large datasets that are costly to store in AGOL and I was wondering if QField has the ability to display datasets from PostgreSQL databases?

I have experimented before with QField and trying to connect to PostgreSQL and even upgrading to the Pro version of the cloud to try to make it work with no help. I understand QField has some sort of 1GB limit but I'm not sure if that pertains to if you are pulling data from a database like PostgreSQL or if that is just direct storage limits. I have about 20GB of data in total (could be more) in my QGIS project. My goal is for my field guys to be able to use QField as a viewer that would display information, Has anyone figured out how to use large datasets from PostgreSQL in QField?